# Register for Push of certain events iOS

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to write an iPhone app in which the user can register for push-notifications in some events. Lets say the app will display 4 different categories. What if the user only wants notifications from 1 or 2 of these categories?

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when user selects these events you can send a call on server (which is generating the push notification) that only these events should generate the push notification and when sending push notification you can check if this device is registered for this particular event's push notification if the user is not registered for this event then don't send the push notification